# Replacing Leading Minus Signs in Environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, matrices, arrays, parsing

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75545/negative-sign-and-matrix-alignment) concerning negative signs and the alignment of entries in matrix environments, Heiko Oberdiek gave a great answer in which he uses a user-defined command called `\matminus` instead of the usual `-`.

How can I define a matrix environment that will automatically perform this replacement of leading negative signs for me?

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**

I have adapted the code provided by Heiko Oberdiek and egreg, and created a package that defines a set of alternate matrix environments (spmatrix, sbmatrix, sBmatrix, svmatrix, and sVmatrix). These environments function analogously to their counterparts without the 's', but reduce the length of the minus signs within them to achieve better alignment of the entries within each column. The project is hosted [here](https://github.com/adityaramesh/smatrix).

Here is a picture that shows the difference between the regular and reduced minus matrix environments:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should consider making the columns right aligned, e.g. by using extra options to matrices provided by `mathtools`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I tried various techniques, including what you suggest, in the question that I link to above. You can see the results in the PDF file that I include with the question -- the right-aligned columns do not look very good when negative signs are used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can make `-` to become `\matminus` in matrices by exploiting the fact that all matrix environments of `amsmath` use `\env@matrix`, by injecting code in it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%%% Save a copy of the original minus in math mode
\mathchardef\realminus\mathcode`-
%%% Define the shortened version of minus (H. Oberdiek)
\newcommand{\reducedminus}{%
  \leavevmode\hphantom{0}%
  \llap{%
    \settowidth{\dimen0 }{$0$}%
    \resizebox{1.1\dimen0 }{\height}{$\realminus$}%
  }%
}
%%% Define \matminus so that it doesn't reduce the minus in sub/superscripts
\newcommand{\matminus}{%
  \mathchoice{\reducedminus}{\reducedminus}%
             {\realminus}{\realminus}%
}

\makeatletter
%%% Make - become \matminus in matrices
\preto\env@matrix{\mathcode`-=\string"8000
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\matminus
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
  -123 & -10 & 1 \\
  100 & 5 & 16 \\
  13 & 7 & 7^{-2}
\end{pmatrix}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I can't see any improvement over the normal appearance

[image]

---

If you want shorter minus signs also in exponents, change the code as follows:

```
%%% Save a copy of the original minus in math mode
\mathchardef\realminus\mathcode`-
%%% Define the shortened version of minus (H. Oberdiek)
\newcommand{\reducedminus}[2]{%
  \leavevmode\hphantom{0}%
  \llap{%
    \settowidth{\dimen0 }{$#10$}%
    \resizebox{1.1\dimen0 }{\height}{$#1\realminus$}%
  }%
}
%%% Define \matminus so that it doesn't reduce the minus in sub/superscripts
\newcommand{\matminus}{\mathpalette\reducedminus\relax}
\makeatletter
%%% Make - become \matminus in matrices
\preto\env@matrix{\mathcode`-=\string"8000
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\matminus
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that the appearance of the first two columns of A has improved, but when exponents are used (as in the third column), there is no difference.

Comment: @void-pointer If you want shorter minus signs also in exponents, some more work is needed. Let me add it, so you can choose.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the result is much better than the unmodified matrix, though the change is subtle.

Comment: @void-pointer I continue to prefer the original.

Comment: I have adapted the code you have provided and created a package that defines a set of alternate matrix environments (spmatrix, sbmatrix, sBmatrix, svmatrix, and sVmatrix), in case others would like to experiment. The project is hosted [here](https://github.com/adityaramesh/smatrix).